# Catching and sending events in python xlib

Tags: python, window-managers

For my window manager project, I'm grabbing all ButtonPress events(so I can focus the window underneath the mouse). If the window is already focused I would like to just pass the event along to the window.

Here's the offending function

```
def left_button(self, event):
    if event.detail == 1 and Configurator.display.get_input_focus().focus == event.window:
        print "Sending Window The Event"
        event.window.send_event(event)
    else:
        try:
            Utils.focus_window(event.window)
        except:
            return
```

The code doesn't fail or send any errors it just doesn't act the way I expect, or any different from the original function(everything after the else statement)

Have I simple forgotten something basic or am I going about this all wrong?